# Is it possible to explicitly set chart colour parameters when plotting charts via the pandas built in data visualisation method?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib, visualization

If using the Pandas built in data visualisation capabilities to plot charts, is it possible to explicitly set the colour parameters for those charts?

If plotting charts via the object oriented method, then it seems quite clear how to proceed, but how would I set the various colours explicitly via the method in question?

For example, is it possible to set the background colour of the axes on the following histrogram to another colour?  If relevant, I think on this particular example, the axes background colour is actually transparent!

[image]

Note: I do realise that it is possible to use matplotlib style sheets, but that is not the specific answer that I am looking for.

Thank you!

Comment: It's possible to create an `ax`, `set_facecolor`, and pass this `ax` to `pd.plot`. Is this an option you are looking for?

Comment: This sounds like we are straying into the object oriented method approach, so I do not think so am afraid.

Comment: Sorry for the wrong answer. Will delete it.

Comment: I don't think it is clear what you're asking here. What is "the Pandas built in data visualisation capabilities"? Why is `plt.rcParams["axes.facecolor"] = "red"` not acceptable?

Comment: That approach sets the area within the axes' border to red.  It is the area behind the numbers and labels on the axes where I want to effect the change.

Comment: Also, I mean the plotting method that deploys the code:

df.plot(kind='hist')

which I understand is built on matplotlib.

The object oriented method gives me the flexibility to colour the area that I want to, but I do not want to have to deploy this method each time (it is more time consuming than a quick plot from the method above).

Hope that is clearer.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah.  Thanks @ImportanceOfBeingEarnest.  I did some more research after your answer and the following does work:

plt.rcParams['figure.facecolor'] = 'red'

This produces:

[image]